# Обновление меток в реальном времени Yandex map api js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, yandex-maps-api

Подскажите как для карты с базой меток сделать обновление в реальном времени при изменении, добавлении или удалении метки из базы? Нужно чтобы на карте метка сразу убиралась или добавлялась. Долго экспериментировал с Ajax, но как надо не работает. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получать обновления в реальном времени есть много разных способов:

Вот некоторые:

- [Long Polling](https://learn.javascript.ru/long-polling)
- [WebSocket](https://learn.javascript.ru/websocket)
- [SSE](https://learn.javascript.ru/server-sent-events)

Описывать как это все работает я не буду, вся подробная информация по ссылкам выше. Все они ведут на [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/). Изучайте.